# md-input maxlength not working

Tags: angular, angular2-material

Even if i add maxLength="250" I can enter value in agular2-material  **md-input**.

[image]

1. Is there anyway i can disable the input field from entering text after 250 char.
2. **Is there any alternative to maxLenth.**

My form input is like :

```
<div class="form-group">
  <md-input type="text" required placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" #nameCountHint
            maxLength="250" class="full-width" dividerColor="{{changeForm.controls.name.valid ? 'primary': 'accent'}}">
    <md-hint align="end">{{nameCountHint.characterCount}} / 250</md-hint>
  </md-input>
  <agile-control-messages color="primary" [control]="teamForm.controls.name"></agile-control-messages>
</div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: can you provide a working fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I found this simple demo on how to have a validation and maybe it could help you.

Component template:

```
 <form [ngFormModel]="someFormHandle" 
            [(ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

            <input class="form-control"
                   [ngFormControl]="someNumber">

            <button class="btn btn-primary" 
                    [disabled]="!someFormHandle.valid">
                    Submit
            </button>
 </form>
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-form',
  templateUrl: './some-form.component.html',
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class SomeForm implements OnInit {

  someFormHandle:ControlGroup;
  someNumber:AbstractControl;

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
  }

  divisibleByTen(control:Control) {
      return parseInt(control.value) % 10 == 0 ? null : {
        divisibleByTen: true
      }
  }

  onSubmit(){
    //Some submit logic
  }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.someFormHandle = this.formBuilder.group({
      'someNumber': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
                                             Validators.maxLength(250), 
                                             this.divisibleByTen])]
    });

    this.someNumber = this.someFormHandle.find('someNumber');
  }

}
```

Comment: md-input-container is not in angular2-material. https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/input/README.md.

Comment: @Karthigeyan, Ow snap! it's Angular2. but have you tried it out?

Comment: I see, I forgot OP referring to the angular2. I was thinking on the first. My bad

Comment: The above thing works fine but i am looking for md-input which has dividerColor etc.

Comment: @Karthigeyan, hey! please have a look in here https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/809